# Hilbert's Nullstellensatz on polynomials with integer coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_m \in \mathbb{Z}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$. Assume $f_1(X) = f_2(X) = \ldots = f_m(X) = 0$ have no solutions over $\mathbb{C}^n$, then by Hilbert's Nullstellensatz, there exists polynomials $g_1, \ldots, g_m \in \mathbb{C}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ such that $1 = f_1 g_1 + \dots f_m g_m$.

In this case, can we always find $g_1, g_2, \ldots, g_m \in \mathbb{Q}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ such that $1 = f_1 g_1 + \dots f_m g_m$? In words, if the coefficients of $f_1, \ldots, f_m$ are all integers, can $g_1, g_2, \ldots, g_m$ be taken as polynomials with integer coefficients, such that $f_1 g_1 + \ldots +f_m g_m \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$?

Added later: I checked Wikipedia on Hilbert's Nullstellensatz. Sorry, it seems to be a stupid question, and the answer is YES.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes.  Given the degrees of the $g_i$, the equation $1 = \sum_i f_i g_i$
is tantamount to a system of linear equations in the coefficients of the $g_i$,
and *those* linear equations have rational coefficients.  Once such a system has
a complex solution it automatically has a rational solution.

Comment: nice argument !

Answer (score 9):

The answer is definitely yes. The argument is very simple: the ring extension $$\mathbb Q[X_1,\dots,X_n]\subset \mathbb C[X_1,\dots,X_n]$$ is faithfully flat.

Comment: Whoa $-$ "very simple" perhaps, but much more advanced
than is necessary; this is just linear algebra in the coefficients.


Comment: Please don't delete this. (For what it's worth this is the first argument that came to my mind, too.)

Comment: I agree with Dan Petersen: Please do not remove
your answer.  There are often very different answers to the same question,
and it can be instructive to see and compare them.  I just didn't want
people to get the idea that they *must* understand concepts like
"faithfully flat" to prove this result.


Comment: @YACP: Sorry, that was not my intent; I guess I should remember that
not everybody here speaks English fluently.  Looking in m-w.com,
"strong reaction of ... astonishment" is the closest to what
I meant, since your answer up to "The argument is very simple"
led me to think you were going to give the elementary linear-algebra
argument, and then suddenly I was whisked into graduate commutative algebra.
@G.Myerson: actually (again going by m-w.com) "subtile" and "subtilities"
are correct albeit old-fashioned alternatives to "subtle" and "subtleties",
and closer to the original Latin *subtilis*.


Comment: Actually the two answers coincide, when you write down the proofs in detail.